# Add units (Neurons) to an existing model in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, transfer-learning

I have trained a model and I want to add more units to it's hidden units and train it for some more epochs. I am implementing a constructive learning algorithm. How can I add neuron to an existing model hidden layer ? And also is there a way to only train the added units parameters and other parameters get freezed ? (In KERAS)

```
def create_first_sub_NN(X):
    sub_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
    h = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid",name="hidden")(sub_input)
    h = tf.keras.Model(inputs=sub_input, outputs=h)
    m_combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([h.input, h.output])
    out = Dense(1, activation="relu")(m_combined)
    out = tf.keras.Model(inputs=sub_input, outputs=out)
    return out

def train_current_model(model,input_groups,Y,error_thr):
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    callbacks = stopAtLossValue()
    # overfitCallback = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=5, 
    patience=10) # if for 10 epochs the error did not decreased more than 5, then stop the current network training
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_absolute_error')

    model.fit(input_groups, train_label, epochs=100, batch_size=32,callbacks=[callbacks])

enter code here

model = create_first_sub_NN(X1_train)
keras.utils.plot_model(model, "first.png",show_shapes=True)
print(model.summary())
list_of_inputs = [sub_X_list[0]]
train_current_model(model, list_of_inputs, train_label, 0.1)
# how to add number of units in my hidden layer for the
enter code here
```

I want to add neuron to my hidden layer repetitively, until my network error gets below the threshold.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @frightera Added

Comment: @ArminSadreddin can we have your code or a simplified version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Instead of adding a neuron to the current layer, We can add another Dense layer which is connected to the next and previous layer and then concatenate the new layer with the old one.[image]